# Perfectly align text to the top of table cell

Tags: html, css

How can i perfectly align text to the top of a table cell? By perfectly, I mean that the top of the letters touch the border of the table cell.

An additional difficulty in my case is that I need to use a *large line height* (approximately double the font height). As a result, there's is a considerable space between the top of the letters and the cell border because the difference between the font height and the line height is distributed equally to both the top and bottom of the text (so called [half-leading](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading)).

I've setup a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njwtk1rk/2/).

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>NOT PROPERLY ALIGNED TO THE TOP</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 

table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
td {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #ddd;    
}
```

Comment: How if you forget about `line-height` and introduce top and bottom padding (bottom only for the `td` you are looking for)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: Looking like this http://jsfiddle.net/njwtk1rk/9/

Comment: You havent told why you need the line height?

Comment: I need the line height because I have several lines of texts that need ample vertical spacing for good readability.

Comment: For a good readability, you'd rather don't need to remove space at top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping necessary text in some spans and adding negative position/margin, like

```
span {
 position: relative;
 top: -12px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/njwtk1rk/7/)

But for a good readability, you'd rather don't need to remove space at top (imho)
Look, [image] the text at left side looks better.

Comment: Similar as Gabriel's answer. Again I'll need to know the height of the font to calculate the margin. Unfortunately, the font family attribute specifies a list of fonts and the fonts have different heights. So the result will only be approximate.

Comment: In reality, there's no colored background and no border. Instead there are elements such as images in other cells on the same table row. And the purpose is in fact to nicely align it with these elements. But technically, it's the same challenge.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your html to:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><span>NOT PROPERLY ALIGNED TO THE TOP</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

adding `<span>` tags
Then you can go:

```
td span {
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Not bad. But I'll need to know the height of the font to calculate the margin. Unfortunately, the font family attribute specifies a list of fonts and the fonts have different heights. So the result will only be approximate.

Comment: I doesn't work like. I guess the CSS is missing `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/njwtk1rk/15/)**

The issue is because of the `line-height`

You can change the line-height of the first line by using the selector `:first-line` like

```
td:first-line {
    line-height: 10px;    
}
```

Comment: Looks very interesting. However, the half-leading is not only removed from above the top but from below the text as well. Therefore, the spacing between the first and second line and the spacing between the other line pairs is different. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njwtk1rk/29/).

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but it goes with JS, not pure CSS only.

HTML (added the 'span' tag inside 'td'):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <span id="myText">PROPERLY ALIGNED TO THE TOP</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var span       = $("#myText");
    var lineHeight = parseInt(span.css("line-height"));
    var fontSize   = parseInt(span.css("font-size"));
    var shift      = (lineHeight-fontSize)/2;
    var shiftPx    = "-"+shift+"px";

    //alert(lineHeight);
    //alert(fontSize);

    span.css({
        "position":"relative",
        "top":shiftPx
    });
});
```

Full jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jondinham/p8g1cx6b/

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I like the approach even though it involves Javascript. However, the solution isn't perfect either. There's still a gap between the border and the top of the letters. I guess that's because the ascender is higher than the typical cap height.